# What is the window of time I have to buy a month subscription for the sender to get its reward?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My friend sent me yesterday a Scroll of Resurrection for World of Warcraft and I activated it.

I was wondering how much time I have to subscribe for a month if I want to be sure he gets his reward.  Is it before the end of 7 free days?

As pointed in the comments, what I'm really looking for is the window of time I have to buy a month to ensure my friend will have its reward for sending a scroll of resurrection.

Thank you.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. This question asks about a scroll of resurrection - the 'duplicate' answer is for a referral. They are two different things.

Comment: I've only been able to find unofficial answers to this question - some say no limit, some estimate a thirty day limit - might be worth submitting a ticket to Blizz support to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll of Resurrection does not currently exist.  (from 2014-08-04 [forum post](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13680928328#1))

Back when the scroll did exist - in-game customer support was able to apply the rewards if you made your case well - even in cases when the scroll was not sent before the re-sub (personal experience).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any definitive proof, but I think they last forever. They may expire based on if/when they change the mount. I know they do last at least 6 months from personal experience, as I invited a friend who said he would come back, then didn't do it for at least 6 months. I still got the mount from the original email I sent him 6 months before.